# Elasticsearch correct way to specify nested field for timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch's documentation states that I can map timestamp to a custom property with the `_timestamp` mapping. The example on their website shows that:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "path" : "post_date"
        }
    }
}
```

Will cause 2009-11-15T14:12:12 to be used as the timestamp value for:

```
{
    "message" : "You know, for Search",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12"
}
```

But what if i wanted to map

```
{
    "message" : "You know, for Search",
    "nested": {
             "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12"
    }
}
```

How can i map my nested `post_date`. What will be the **path** property?

**EDIT**: in my properties mapping, i didn't provide the `"type":"nested"` property  for my nested objects , I just provided their subproperties in their `properties` property. This the default  properties mapping generated by ES 1.4.1 during the first indexing.

Comment: nested.post_data should work fine. Is the the field called "nested" , a nested type ?

Comment: I hope my edit answers your question

Comment: What you suggested works. Please create an answer from it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give complete path while accessing nested fields.
In this case , you can use this - "nested.post_data"